# Change function doesn't work on tablet but yes in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a div with class 'send' which appears when #myRange changes its value in mobile and tablet. In desktop I use ' on click'.

In mobile and desktop it's working well but i can't see why is not working on tablet. It does not add the class visible to the #myRange.

```js
var mediaQueries = {
  tablet: window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)'),
  xl: window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)'),
}

if(!mediaQueries.tablet.matches){
  console.log('mobile or tablet');
  $('#myRange').change(function(){ 
    $('.send').addClass('visible');
  });
} else {
  $('#myRange').on('click', function(){ 
    $('.send').addClass('visible');
    $('.myRange').addClass('mouse-visible');
  });
  console.log('desktop');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in `$('.myRange').addClass('mouse-visible');` where you refer to an element with the *class* myRange instead of the *id*. You could also use `$(this)` if you refer to the element which is clicked

Comment: Is `myRange` both a class and an id?

Comment: @xKobaltYes It is. Is there any problem?

Comment: @Koen But class myRange also exists

Comment: @Vander No there is no problem.  It would be helpful if you could create a sandbox. 
as a problem could be with you CSS or HTML also.

Comment: @Vander Your question states: "It does not add the class visible to the #myRange."
Nowhere in your code do you attempt to add the class visible to `$('#myRange')`

Comment: @Koen Yup sorry, my fault, i mean when I click on #myRange' the div with class 'send' has to appear.